# in Assembly Language, what does Call 0032112B means?

Tags: assembly, x86, ollydbg

Im not really that familiar with Assembly so when I come across a code like this

> Call 0032112B

I'm a bit confused if 0032112B is a memory address (dump), the address of the code where it will go next or what.

The question is whenever I come across this kind of code, where do I need to look? and what is the call instrcution going to do with that memory / or value of that memory?

BTW, im using ollydbg.

Thanks

Comment: Is this x86 assembly? Yes, `0032112B` is the hexadecimal address of the subroutine that will be called. It will follow the CPU's calling convention (pushing the program counter of the following instruction onto the stack), call the subroutine, and then return when it encounters the `ret` (return) instruction (the return works by popping the previously saved program counter and jumping to it)

Comment: I would recommend you get a book on Intel assembly language. The instructions won't make much sense until then.

Comment: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most certainly an address of a procedure to where the call is being made. The call instruction branches to the specified address after it saves some of the values onto it's stack segment.

If you are interested in assembly level programming, then *Microprocessors and interfacing* by Douglas V Hall is a good place to start.

I agree that it's based on an obsolete processor but you'll get the foundation strong.